# How to configure mvc to support binding dd/MM/yyyy date formates for all cultures?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, datetimeoffset, uiculture

I have MVC web application and I am supporting 2 languages(Arabic, English).

I have post-action which takes the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

When UI language is English it serializes the following date formate **"dd/MM/yyyy"** perfectly after adding globalization config inside web.config:

> `<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />`

but when UI language is Arabic they are serialized into 0001-01-01T00:00:00 +00:00 (even the value posted by Jquery is startDate: 26/08/2020)

So how can I configure my web application to support binding the **"dd/MM/yyyy"** format for all cultures?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
```